# turning jquery function into angular-directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following (working) jQuery function to check if elements with the class ".overflow" are overflowed and have an ellipsis:

```
 function isOverflowEllipsis() {
    $('.overflow').each(function (){
        var clone = $(this).clone();
        clone.css({"overflow":"visible"});
        clone.addClass("clone");
        clone.appendTo('.atc');
        var cloneScrollWidth = clone.get(0).scrollWidth;
        var cloneClientWidth = clone.get(0).clientWidth;
        $('.clone').remove();       
        if(cloneScrollWidth > cloneClientWidth){
            console.log("true");            
        }
        else {
            console.log("false");   

        }
    });
}
```

Now I want to use this functionality in my AngularJS app. How can I turn it into a working directive? I want to use jqLite only. I am new to custom directives and I can't get it to work ;-(

This is my unsuccessful try:

```
 app.directive("isOverflowEllipsis", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {          
                var clone = elem.clone();
                clone.css({"overflow":"visible"});
                clone.addClass("clone");
                clone.append('.overflow');
                var cloneScrollWidth = clone.scrollWidth;
                var cloneClientWidth = clone.clientWidth;
                $('.clone').removeClass();      
                if(cloneScrollWidth > cloneClientWidth){
                    console.log("true");            
                }
                else {
                    console.log("false");                   
                }           
        }
    };
});
```

Edit: in jQuery the function is within a `$(document).ready(function(){...}` and in a `$(window).resize(function() {...}`. How do I have to do this in the directive?

Answer (score 0):

```
 link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {          
            var clone = angular.copy(elem);
            attrs.overflow="visible";
            clone .addClass("clone");
            clone .append('.overflow');
            var cloneScrollWidth = attrs.scrollWidth;
            var cloneClientWidth = attrs.clientWidth;
            elem.removeClass('clone');      
            if(cloneScrollWidth > cloneClientWidth){
                console.log("true");            
            }
            else {
                console.log("false");                   
            }           
    }
```

Comment: what did you change in the author code and need explanation for your answer

Comment: No, sorry. Here the cloning part is missing. I have to create a clone of the element to detect the overflow and then remove the cloned element again out of the DOM. The overflow of the original element should stay hidden (and is undetectable like this, that's why I create a clone).

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately still not working correctly. I think there is a problem with the method scrollWidth and clientWidth in jqLite.

Comment: In jQuery I used `clone.get(0).scrollWidth;` But how can I use this correctly in jqLite?

Comment: use clone.attr('attribute name')